# Unable to remove old kernels: Stuck at "Building dependency tree ... 50%"

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I have to remove old kernels because I don't have enough space on boot partition but I can't. I'm trying:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

but the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree ... 50%
```

and it ends.

Output of `ls -l /boot`

```
total 217038
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1162712 lip 15  2014 abi-3.13.0-32-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165260 paź  7 18:34 abi-3.13.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165260 paź 23 16:39 abi-3.13.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165260 lis  6 20:57 abi-3.13.0-68-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165260 lis 16 20:57 abi-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165260 gru  1 05:29 abi-3.13.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165611 lip 15  2014 config-3.13.0-32-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165763 paź  7 18:34 config-3.13.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165763 paź 23 16:39 config-3.13.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165763 lis  6 20:57 config-3.13.0-68-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165763 lis 16 20:57 config-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165763 gru  1 05:29 config-3.13.0-71-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 sty  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 gru  6 17:36 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28334366 paź 31 21:31 initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20015454 paź 31 22:09 initrd.img-3.13.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20012878 lis  5 17:59 initrd.img-3.13.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20015434 lis 10 11:38 initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20015526 gru  1 11:02 initrd.img-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20015136 gru  6 17:35 initrd.img-3.13.0-71-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 paź 31 21:21 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3381262 lip 15  2014 System.map-3.13.0-32-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3392380 paź  7 18:34 System.map-3.13.0-66-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3392383 paź 23 16:39 System.map-3.13.0-67-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3392383 lis  6 20:57 System.map-3.13.0-68-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3392660 lis 16 20:57 System.map-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3392660 gru  1 05:29 System.map-3.13.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5798112 paź 31 21:25 vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5820544 paź  7 18:34 vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5822456 paź 31 21:30 vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  5822368 paź 23 16:39 vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5824280 lis  5 17:59 vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  5822400 lis  6 20:57 vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5824312 lis 10 11:38 vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  5823104 lis 16 20:57 vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5825016 gru  1 11:02 vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic.efi.signed
-rw------- 1 root root  5823584 gru  1 05:29 vmlinuz-3.13.0-71-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5825496 gru  6 17:36 vmlinuz-3.13.0-71-generic.efi.signed
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the output of `ls -l /boot` please? Also have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: I've tried :   sudo apt-get autoremove but   the result is the same

Comment: Any errors on `sudo apt-get check` or `sudo dpkg --audit`?

Comment: sudo apt-get check  gives the same result  and after   sudo dpkg --audit nothing happens

Comment: It's very probably not stuck, just taking some time to finish. How long have you waited?

Comment: I've waited just a few seconds an it ends i strange way it shows :   marcin@marcin-X550LC:~$ ... 50%

Comment: When I start my ubuntu I receive a communicate that Ubuntu has experienced en internal error an I don't know how to fix it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've linked the question as a duplicate, but here are some steps to get you moving in the meantime.

The fact that the apt-get commands aren't working suggests that there are some deeper problems within your package management system.

First try purging the old kernel:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

If that doesn't work you may have to go into boot and remove them by hand.
Be very careful to type this command carefully, if you delete stuff that you're not meant to it could leave your system in an unusable state.

```
sudo rm /boot/*3.13.0-32-*
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I've done:  sudo rm /boot/*3.13.0-32-* and then I've made update and then sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic worked . I don't know how it happened but not everything is fine :) thanks for help

Comment: No problem @marcinn714 if you could show your appreciation by clicking on the tick or check mark to the left of my answer I'd be much obliged!